# Конвертация ассоциативного массива с JavaScript в C# через JSon

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Добрый вечер.

Нужно с JavaScript отправить в контроллер ассоциативный массив через JSON.

Функционал для отправки есть, данные приходят, только я не могу разобраться, как их распарсить.

В JavaScript массив заполняю так

```
this._phraseCollection = []; 

   this._itemsCollection.push(
      {
          Id: someId,
          Name: someName,
          Text: someText
      }
    );
```

На стороне C# есть класс, соответственно

```
public class Items
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

В контроллере пробовал принимать объект как `List<Items>`, `Items[]`, `Object[]` , 
в дебаге отображается, что что-то есть, но как вытянуть нужные данные?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с Json.Net, вот такая строчка десериализует на ура

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Items>>(json);
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json
**update**
добавил var result

Comment: А тип какой использовать? В DeserializeObject принимается string, а у меня массив

Comment: json - это строка

Comment: да, но если тип переменной в которую будет приходить значение с `JavaScript`'a будет string - то оно бует null, а, если массив - то в дебаге будет видно,что в масиве есть элементы. `JSON` приходит в таком виде [ссылка](http://piccy.info/view3/8462640/e2c31c43d2bdf87e40cafb731a27a6c0/)

Comment: @LocalUser Теория которая стоит за всем действом очень проста, на серверной части (C#) вы создаете класс публичные свойства которого повторяют JSON. А сам JSON - это текст, где используя JSON нотацию описывают объект. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: @LocalUser судя по "картинке" C# класс должен выглядеть как-то так public Result {public int Page{get;set;} public int Records{get;set;} public int Total{get;set;} public List<Cell> Rows{get;set;}}; public class Cell {public string Id{get;set;} public List<string> Cell{get;set;}

Comment: @LocalUser, и опять же судя по скриншоту нет там структуры       {
          Id: someId,
          Name: someName,
          Text: someText
      }

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Предложная реализация с десериализатором работает! Проблема была в незнании некоторых "внутренных" особенностей системы, которую использую.